# Hide list element if $count variable has value zero

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I want to hide the category element `<li>` if the product `$count` has value zero.
This is the page I'm working on: http://www.hotsales.com.br/procurar/

"Categorias" is the Categories filter. If the category line has zero product, it must be hidden (maybe `style="display: none;"`). When selecting some Store (Loja), many categories will be listed like "Computers (0)" when should not be displayed because the store may be about shoes.

I've tried putting this at the end of the foreach loop `if ($count = 0) {document.getElementByTagName("li").style.display = "none"}` but  doesn't work. This is the actual whole function which displays the filter. The `<li>` element is echo generated 4 lines after $count is defined:

```
/*
List categories on the search sidebar
*/
if( !function_exists( 'list_search_sidebar_cats' ) ){
function list_search_sidebar_cats( $ancestors, $parent, $selected = '', $search_show_count, $permalink ){
global $slugs;
$children = get_terms( 'offer_cat', array( 'parent' => $parent ) );
if( !empty( $children ) ){
    echo '<ul class="list-unstyled">';
    foreach( $children as $child ){
        $li_class = in_array( $child->term_id, $ancestors ) ? 'active' : '';
        if( !empty( $selected ) ){
            $li_class .= $child->slug == $selected->slug ? ' current' : '';
        }

        $count = '';
        if( $search_show_count == 'yes' ){
            $count = custom_term_count( $child, 'offer_cat' );
        }



        if( empty( $ancestors ) || ( !empty( $ancestors ) && in_array( $child->term_id, $ancestors ) ) || ( !empty( $ancestors ) && !empty( $selected ) && $child->parent == $selected->term_id ) ){
            echo '<li style="display:flex;" class="'.esc_attr( $li_class ).'"><a href="javascript:;" data-cat="'.esc_attr( $child->slug ).'">'.$child->name.' <span class="count">('.$count.')</span></a>';
            if( !empty( $li_class ) ){
                list_search_sidebar_cats( $ancestors, $child->term_id, $selected, $search_show_count, $permalink );
                echo '</li>';
     }
            else{
                echo '</li>';
            }
     }

    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

}
}

Comment: `if ($count = 0)` is a wrong syntax.

Comment: write it directly into the `<li>` element when echoing it! `<li style="display: none;">`

Comment: `empty( $ancestors ) || ( !empty( $ancestors )`, uuuhhh, what now? It kinda seems obsolete to add this.

Comment: `document.getElementByTagName("li").style.display = "none"` won't work. `getElementByTagName` returns an array-like object. You need to loop through that and then use `style.display = 'none'` in the loop on each element

Comment: Thank you all! Jeff's suggestion solved the problem perfectly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to put javascript into that play to change it after it was rendered.
You can easily just include it to the initial output:

```
// please review your conditions here, they don't make too much sense.
//      if this is true    then this is false   (and vice versa)
if( empty( $ancestors ) || ( !empty( $ancestors ) && in_array( $child->term_id, $ancestors ) ) || ( !empty( $ancestors ) && !empty( $selected ) && $child->parent == $selected->term_id ) ){
       // here's the fix:
       $display = $count>0 ? "flex" : "none";
       echo '<li style="display:'.$display.';" class="'.esc_attr( $li_class ).'"><a href="javascript:;" data-cat="'.esc_attr( $child->slug ).'">'.$child->name.' <span class="count">('.$count.')</span></a>';
       if( !empty( $li_class ) ){
            list_search_sidebar_cats( $ancestors, $child->term_id, $selected, $search_show_count, $permalink );
            echo '</li>';
       } else{
            echo '</li>';
       }
}
```

Comment: Hi Jeff.. with your code, all the `li` elements are being hidden. Inspected them on Mozilla, they are rendered, but with `display: none`. Do you think it is something about $count? Thanks

Comment: Now it WORKS! Thank you, Jeff! Really it was because the $count function was returning the value inside an tag. `return '<span class="count">'.$count.'</span>';` So I changed it to just `return $count;` GOD bless you!!

Comment: For the commentary edit, +1. Let's just bless god if he could somehow forward this information to @Eric.

Comment: Altruistic people are the God's hands here on earth, just like was the good Samaritan. Surely, GOD will reward all these people.